# Insect data and number of factors in exploratory factor analysis

Tags: self-study, factor-analysis

I was doing some exploratory factoring analysis in a dataset on two species of insect with 7 variables, until I get into a situation of not knowing how to choose the number of factors.

[image]

```
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  2  and the number of components =  NA
```

The plot above and MAP output from `vss()` in `pysch` package suggests 2 factors.

```
Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin factor adequacy
Call: KMO(r = insect)
Overall MSA =  0.69
MSA for each item = 
  CA   LA  C3P  L3P  C4P C12A C13A 
0.76 0.77 0.74 0.81 0.76 0.58 0.56
```

The solution with 2 factors is below

```
Factor Analysis using method =  ml
Call: fa(r = insect, nfactors = 2, rotate = "varimax", fm = "ml")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
       ML2    ML1    h2    u2  com
CA   0.783  0.310 0.709 0.291 1.31
LA   0.685  0.142 0.490 0.510 1.09
C3P  0.519  0.048 0.272 0.728 1.02
L3P  0.466  0.078 0.223 0.777 1.06
C4P  0.641 -0.005 0.410 0.590 1.00
C12A 0.163  0.804 0.674 0.326 1.08
C13A 0.097  0.993 0.995 0.005 1.02

                        ML2   ML1
SS loadings           2.016 1.757
Proportion Var        0.288 0.251
Cumulative Var        0.288 0.539
Proportion Explained  0.534 0.466
Cumulative Proportion 0.534 1.000
```

The first thing I noticed is that 2 factors only accounts 53.9% of variation in the data and have communalities under 0.3 in the variables C3P and L3P and lower than 0.5 in LA and C4P too. I also have in the CA variable loadings in 2 factors what sounds like a little of problem based on what I read.

I tried solutions with 3 factors

```
Factor Analysis using method =  ml
Call: fa(r = insect, nfactors = 3, rotate = "varimax", fm = "ml")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
        ML1   ML2   ML3    h2    u2  com
CA    0.307 0.653 0.378 0.664 0.336 2.09
LA    0.132 0.757 0.142 0.610 0.390 1.13
C3P   0.040 0.192 0.834 0.734 0.266 1.11
L3P   0.072 0.523 0.057 0.281 0.719 1.06
C4P  -0.008 0.497 0.404 0.410 0.590 1.92
C12A  0.803 0.178 0.028 0.677 0.323 1.10
C13A  0.992 0.092 0.049 0.995 0.005 1.02

                        ML1   ML2   ML3
SS loadings           1.748 1.596 1.028
Proportion Var        0.250 0.228 0.147
Cumulative Var        0.250 0.478 0.625
Proportion Explained  0.400 0.365 0.235
Cumulative Proportion 0.400 0.765 1.000
```

and 4 factors

```
Factor Analysis using method =  ml
Call: fa(r = insect, nfactors = 4, rotate = "varimax", fm = "ml")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
       ML2   ML4   ML1    ML3    h2    u2  com
CA   0.305 0.601 0.308  0.219 0.597 0.403 2.37
LA   0.104 0.861 0.107  0.083 0.771 0.229 1.08
C3P  0.032 0.175 0.965  0.178 0.995 0.005 1.14
L3P  0.072 0.459 0.033  0.191 0.254 0.746 1.40
C4P  0.023 0.343 0.218  0.911 0.995 0.005 1.41
C12A 0.804 0.169 0.017  0.065 0.679 0.321 1.10
C13A 0.989 0.117 0.052 -0.018 0.995 0.005 1.03

                        ML2   ML4   ML1   ML3
SS loadings           1.735 1.505 1.090 0.957
Proportion Var        0.248 0.215 0.156 0.137
Cumulative Var        0.248 0.463 0.618 0.755
Proportion Explained  0.328 0.285 0.206 0.181
Cumulative Proportion 0.328 0.613 0.819 1.000
```

I know that the more factors greater the ratio of variance explained. What makes me think if I should consider solutions with 3 or 4 factors are the communalities of the variables. However, factors 3 and 4 in short represent only a single variable.

**EDIT:** I was thinking if EFA is appropriate in this case, because looking to the correlation plot below, I see that the structure of interdependence between variables is very weak.

[image]

**`EDIT2:`** Some more outputs

```
Tucker Lewis Index of factoring reliability =  0.9965
RMSEA index =  0.0374  and the 90 % confidence intervals are  0 0.1432
BIC =  -25.79
Fit based upon off diagonal values = 0.983
Measures of factor score adequacy             
                                                    ML2   ML1
Correlation of (regression) scores with factors   0.898 0.996
Multiple R square of scores with factors          0.807 0.993
Minimum correlation of possible factor scores     0.614 0.986
```

Comment: Do you have model fit indexes to accompany your 2-factor solution (RMSEA and TLI)?

Comment: @jsakaluk I added that to the question now.

Comment: 53.9% of total explained variance is really good for factor analysis! Remember you are doing FA, not PCA. Communality of 0.3 is not a problem, a variable must have unique variation and that one often is not less than the variable's common variation. For only 7 variables, 2 (maximum 3) factor solution is a way to go. Scree plot should normally be plotted with eigenvalues of components, not of the factors: scree plot is a tool to decide on the number of factors before factors are extracted.

Comment: For EFA, the main criterion is how well your number of factors reproduce correlation matrix. Choose the smallest number of factors that do it reasonably well.